# Variable updated inside the signal handler never gets updated

Tags: c, linux, handler, signals

In a signal handler, I'm changing the value of a variable. However, the program never notices the update, even though I've declared the variable **leader_barrier** as **sig_atomic_t**.

```
void timer_action(int signum)
{   
static int count = 0;

 if ( !(*pbarrier_in_proc) && !(leader_barrier) && !(*pno_more) )
  leader_barrier = 1;
}
```

And its confirmed that **timer_action** does execute and **leader_barrier** does become 1 inside it, as I have seen it by printing its values inside the signal handler.

Comment: What do you mean the program never notices the update? Show how you are using that variable elsewhere.

Comment: Elsewhere that variable is only read, never written. And the program does read it after this signal handler is called, but still can't see the update. Strange!

Answer (score 6):

You should declare `leader_barrier` as `volatile sig_atomic_t`, not just `sig_atomic_t`.  Otherwise the compiler is free to assume the variable does not change asynchronously.  That is, it may read it once at the start of the function (say) and, assuming no other functions that could change `leaderboard` get called, it need not read it again.

Comment: volatile sig_atomic_t leader_barrier;

Comment: Then it is going to take a bit more context to determine what is going on.  How is the variable declared/defined?  What is the code that is checking it?  Are you certain the code to check it is being executed?  Is optimization turned on?  (Sorry to be bombarding you with questions.)

Comment: I've also checked the addresses, they are the same. By the way, My program is multithreaded, but this variable is global. This problem is really frustrating me. If problems like these keep creeping, then Jesus! what will I do :(!

Comment: Yes andrew the code do get executed, and when I print the value, its 1 inside the signal handler but always 0 elsewhere! Even after a long time it has been set to 1.

Comment: You say you print the variables value in the signal handler, do you also print it where you are reading it?  Does that print get executed and print zero, or does it just not execute?  Edit: whoops, you answered me as I was asking.  No optimization?!  Hm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the two variables are not the same variable.  Try printing their addresses in both the signal handler and the other code in question.

Comment: I've confirmed that the addresses are the same